# More pythonic way to parse some values from a few elements from a list?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Is there a more pythonic way to write this code? this field_split variable becomes part of a mysql statement. I need to reformat these 5 time fields using `dateutil.parser.parse` and make the field `None` if the timestamp value was empty in the incoming CSV file that i parsed in to `field_split`.   [6],[7],[8],[9],[44] are the columns that are timestamps is this table.  I feel like there should be a way to consolidate this code more but not sure how.

```
                if field_split[6]:
                    field_split[6]= dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[6])
                else:
                    field_split[6]=None

                if field_split[7]:
                    field_split[7]= dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[7])
                else:
                    field_split[7] = None

                if field_split[8]:
                    field_split[8]= dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[8])
                else:
                    field_split[8] = None

                if field_split[9]:
                    field_split[9]= dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[9])
                else:
                    field_split[9] = None

                if field_split[44]:
                    field_split[44] = dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[44])
                else:
                    field_split[44] = None
```

Comment: What does it mean to be pythonic or more pythonic?

Answer (score 2):

It feels like a loop would be appropriate here:

```py
time_fields = [6,7,8,9,44]
for v in time_fields:
    if field_split[v]:
        field_split[v] = dateutil.parser.parse(field_split[v])
     else:
        field_split[v] = None
```

An other, more condensed,  way of doing it...

```py
set_ = field_split.__setitem__; parse_ = dateutil.parser.parse
[set_(i, parse_(field_split[i])) if field_split[i] else set_(i, None) for i in time_fields]
```

Answer (score 1):

Reuse `field_split[timestamp]` as `data` in the next if-else statement.

```
timestamps = [6, 7, 8, 9, 44]
for timestamp in timestamps:
    data = field_split[timestamp]
    field_split[timestamp] = dateutil.parser.parse(data) if data else None
```